Model artifacts after rigging
I'm making my first character mostly following tutorial on YouTube. After rigging the body and assigning vertexes to bones I get strange artifacts on legs. It doesn't happen on any other bones. What can cause this behaviour? Besides things happening in the video I did also a bit of sculpting.


Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

That screenshot has the quality of a webp from 2005. You gotta do better. It’s so bad, the only think I can see looks off in the legs might just be taken for JPEG artifacts if I wasn’t looking for something there.
